# How to fix an error when adding a manual scale in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I add a manual scale like in the example below. I get the following error message:

> "Warning message:
>   In if (self$guide == "none") return() :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

What is causing this error message and how do I solve it?

Your help is much appreciated!

```
d <- data.frame(week = seq(1, 52, 1), 
            revenue = round(runif(52, 0, 100)), 0)

p <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = week, y = revenue, fill = 'lightskyblue')) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', colour = 'black') 


p <- p + scale_fill_identity(name = NULL,
                             guide = guide_legend(label.position = 'top'),
                             labels = c('2019'))

p
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, and I can't find something wrong with your (well-crafted) mwe. I suggest you report it as an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues). (There are two instances of `(self$guide == "none")` in the source, one in [`ScaleDiscreteIdentity`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/652a43189388d185a4d96c1f83cb6e06d00b8b06/R/scale-identity.r#L149), one in [`ScaleContinuousIdentity`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/652a43189388d185a4d96c1f83cb6e06d00b8b06/R/scale-identity.r#L170), my guess is that you trigger the second but both are susceptible.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I posted it as an issue (#3127).

Answer (score 7):

## Short answer

Upvoted for a self-contained MCVE, though I'd like to emphasize that you got a *warning* message, not an error. In this particular case, **you don't need to fix anything**. You can ignore the message, as the code works perfectly fine as intended.

## Longer explanation

As @r2evans noted, this is due to the `scale_*_identity` code [[found here]](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/scale-identity.r). As described in `?scale_fill_identity`, these scales do not produce a legend by default, though you can override that by substituting the `guide = "none"` argument with other types of guides.

**How it's supposed to work:**

This legend-creation behaviour is coded in the `train` function for `ScaleDiscreteIdentity` / `ScaleContinuousIdentity`, which checks to see whether the guide parameter's value is "none". If so, create no legend. Otherwise, use the `train` function from `ScaleDiscrete` / `ScaleContinuous` to create the appropriate legend:

```
ScaleDiscreteIdentity <- ggproto("ScaleDiscreteIdentity", ScaleDiscrete,
  ...,
  train = function(self, x) {
    # do nothing if no guide, otherwise train so we know what breaks to use
    if (self$guide == "none") return()
    ggproto_parent(ScaleDiscrete, self)$train(x)
  }
)

ScaleContinuousIdentity <- ggproto("ScaleContinuousIdentity", ScaleContinuous,
  ...,
  train = function(self, x) {
    # do nothing if no guide, otherwise train so we know what breaks to use
    if (self$guide == "none") return()
    ggproto_parent(ScaleContinuous, self)$train(x)
  }
)
```

The examples in `?scale_fill_identity` indicate that `guide = "legend"` can be used instead of `guide = "none"`. In practice, `guide = guide_legend(...)` can also be used. In fact, `?guides` states:

> `guide = "legend"` in `scale_*` is syntactic sugar for `guide = guide_legend()`

**How it actually works** (at least based on my current version 3.1.0):

For `scale_*_identity`, there **is** a subtle difference between `guide = "legend"` and `guide = guide_legend(...)`. I've trimmed down the MCVE to illustrate the point:

```
p <- ggplot(data = d, 
            aes(x = week, y = revenue, fill = 'lightskyblue')) + 
  geom_col()

p1 <- p + scale_fill_identity(guide = guide_legend())
p2 <- p + scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend")
p3 <- p + scale_fill_identity(guide = "none")
```

[image: plot]

Both p1 and p2 results in the same legend, yet p1 triggers the warning, while p2 does not. (p3, of course, uses the default option and triggers no warning.) The reason for this difference lies in their fill scales, which can be found at `p<1/2/3>$scales$scales[[1]]`:

```
> p1$scales$scales[[1]]$guide
$`title`
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "waiver"

$title.position
NULL

$title.theme
NULL

... #omitted for space. it goes on for a while

> p2$scales$scales[[1]]$guide
[1] "legend"

> p3$scales$scales[[1]]$guide
[1] "none"
```

`p1$scales$scales[[1]]$guide` has 21 items, while `p2$scales$scales[[1]]$guide` and `p3$scales$scales[[1]]$guide` each comprises of a single character string. As such, when the `train` function checks for `self$guide == "none"`, p1 returns a list of TRUE / FALSE values, one for each item, while p2 and p3 returns a single TRUE / FALSE.

```
> p1$scales$scales[[1]]$guide == "none"
         title title.position    title.theme    title.hjust    title.vjust          label 
         FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE 
label.position    label.theme    label.hjust    label.vjust       keywidth      keyheight 
         FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE 
     direction   override.aes           nrow           ncol          byrow        reverse 
         FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE 
         order  available_aes           name 
         FALSE          FALSE          FALSE 
> p2$scales$scales[[1]]$guide == "none"
[1] FALSE
> p3$scales$scales[[1]]$guide == "none"
[1] TRUE
```

Since the `train` function only expects a single value to be returned from its `self$guide == "none"` check, p1 triggers the warning message for condition length > 1.

**Does it matter**:

Not really. When faced with a list of 21 TRUE / FALSE values from p1, the `train` function only looks at the first one---which is FALSE because `p1$scales$scales[[1]]$guide$title`'s default value is `waiver()`. So p1's `guide = guide_legend()` checks out the same way as p2's `guide = "legend"`. You can ignore the warning and carry on.

... Just don't name your legend title "none" within `guide_legend`:

```
p4 <- p + scale_fill_identity(guide = guide_legend(title = "none"))
# this will cause the legend to disappear, because the first value in
# p4$scales$scales[[1]]$guide == "none" will actually be TRUE
```

**Should it be addressed anyway**:

Yes, though I'd say it's not a critical bug, as the code generally behaves as intended (p4 above is a fringe case).

I imagine the fix should be pretty simple anyway, e.g.:

```
# this
if (all(self$guide == "none")) return() 

# instead of this
if (self$guide == "none") return()
```

Comment: Thanks for digging into the code base and figuring this out. You are correct, it should be fixed. At the same time, I'd like to mention that the code example is backwards. Manual scales should be done with `scale_*_manual()`, not with `scale_*_identity()` (see my answer).

Comment: @ClausWilke I completely agree. This is an answer to illustrate the technical part. I've tried to think of legit use cases where one may conceivably want a legend with `scale_*_identity`... all I managed to come up with were self-demonstration for colour / shape / linetype / etc. values. :)

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by Z.lin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54586124/4975218) does a great job figuring out what is going wrong here. It is indeed a bug in ggplot2. However, I'd like to use this opportunity to point out that your code is backwards. You shouldn't normally use a guide with `scale_*_identity()`, since the identity scales take data values and show them as is (i.e., without a mapping that needs to be shown in a guide). Therefore, these scales are not meant to have a legend.

If you want manually color elements, then in the aesthetic mapping you should use the data value that is represented (here, `fill = '2019'`) and then use `scale_fill_manual()` to map that data value to a color. Notice how in this case there is no warning, because `scale_*_manual()` has been tested extensively with different guide code variations, whereas `scale_*_identity()` has not.

```r
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(week = seq(1, 52, 1), 
                revenue = round(runif(52, 0, 100)), 0)

ggplot(data = d, aes(x = week, y = revenue, fill = '2019')) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', colour = 'black') +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(`2019` = 'lightskyblue'),
    name = NULL,
    guide = guide_legend(label.position = 'top')
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>